# Application client cannot find a SQL connection

Tags: sql, windows, odbc

Running Windows 2019 servers in my lab.
An application has a SQL client. But the client cannot find an ODBC connection.
Created a "System DSN" via the ODBC Data Source administrator (32-bit). As I usually do in my lab. I found some articles on registry placement, all appear OK. I compare another server and that machine has no issue.
Both 2019 servers are on the latest MS hotfixes.
I'm found no specific articles that can help me isolate the fault. I see no errors in the Windows Event Logs.
ODBC System DSN passes testing in the configuration window.
Can anyone help?

Comment: When working with ODBC Data Source Administrator I often create my connections in both the 32-bit and 64-bit dialogs just to be sure that I didnt create them in the wrong one. Could be worth trying before troubleshooting further. Also, welcome to Stack Oversflow!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?`

Comment: "Which dbms"? The MS SQL 2017.

Comment: Still an issue after creating a 64-bit record